# Primefaces 3.0 : TreeNode and ContextMenu

Tags: java, jsf, jsf-2, primefaces

In my application, I have a tree with various object types (sources, tables, etc).
I'd like to enable a context menu for the different types of object (add, delete, edit etc).

How can I use context menu on tree nodes in Primefaces ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Never did it in practice (I am still on Primefaces 2.x), but from theory the facelet code should look something like this:

```
<h:form>
  <p:tree value="#{myBean.tree}" var="node" id="tree"
          selectionMode="single" selection="#{myBean.selectedNode}">
     <p:treeNode>
        <h:outputText value="#{node}" />
     </p:treeNode>
  </p:tree>

  <p:contextMenu for="tree" id="menu">
    <p:menuitem value="Add" actionListener="#{myBean.add}" />
     ...
  </p:contextMenu>
</h:form>
```

Usage of `p:contextMenu` and `p:tree` is shown in [Primefaces showcase](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase-labs/ui/home.jsf).

Comment: the contextMenu doesn't appear at the point of the mouse but far below. The method myBean.selectedNode is not called (neither setSelectedNode) :\

Comment: Tree and ContextMenu are fully supported now! Check out this showcase: http://www.primefaces.org/showcase-labs/ui/treeContextMenu.jsf